# What are the roles of _read and read in Node JS streams?

Tags: node.js

I'm really just looking for clarification on how these work. IMO the documentation on streams is somewhat lacking, and there actually aren't a lot of resources out their that comprehensively explain explain how they're are meant to work and be extended.

My question can be broken down into two parts

One, What is the role of the `_read` function within the stream module? When I run this code it endlessly prints out "hello world" until null is pushed onto the stream buffer. This seems to indicate that `_read` is called in some kind of loop that waits for a null in the buffer, but I can't find documentation anywhere that states this in explicit terms.

```
var Readable = require('stream').Readable
var rs = Readable()

rs._read = function () {
    rs.push("hello world")
    rs.push(null)
};

rs.on("data", function(data){
    console.log("some data", data)
})
```

Two, what does `read` actually do? My understanding is that read consumes data from the read stream buffer, and fires the `data` event. Is that all that's going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`read()` is something that a consumer of the readStream calls if they want to specifically read some bytes from the stream (when the stream is not flowing).

`_read()` is an internal method that is part of the internal implementation of the read stream.  The internals of the stream call this method (it is NOT to be called from the outside) when the stream is flowing and the stream wants to get more data from the source.  When called the `_read()` method pushes data with `.push(data)` or if it has no more data, then it does a `.push(null)`.

You can see an explanation and example here in [this article](https://medium.com/autodesk-tlv/streams-in-depth-in-node-js-c8cc7f1eb0d6#f227).

```
_read(size) {
    if (this.data.length) {
        const chunk = this.data.slice(0, size);
        this.data = this.data.slice(size, this.data.length);               
        this.push(chunk);        
    } else {
        this.push(null); // 'end', no more data
    }
}
```

If you were implementing a read stream to some custom source of data, then you would implement the `_read()` method to fetch up to the `size` amount of data from your source and `.push()` that data into the stream.

Comment: Thank you, am I correct in saying that _read is called in a loop when the stream class is instantiated?

Comment: @Carl - You can study the code yourself.  Here's where [in the src](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/_stream_readable.js#L493) `._read()` is called.  It's not called inside a loop.  The idea for `_read(size)` is that it's supposed to give you as much data as is available up to `size`. so it would only get called again after some of the data has been delivered to whomever is reading the data from the stream and the buffer again has room (or is empty).